# Python Sh package, how to pass unknown number of arguments?

Tags: python, synchronization, aws-cli

Im using the sh package to execute some aws cli commands.

I have multiple named flags to pass to the command..

```
s3=sh.aws.bake('s3')
s3.sync(origin, destination, exclude="a", exclude="b")
```

However, I don't know how many excludes I have.  They are stored in a list.

I tried this, which looks like it should work but it doesn't...

```
sync = s3.sync
for pattern in exclude:
    sync = sync.bake("--exclude=\""+pattern+"\"")

s3.sync(origin, destination)
```

it does append the args, as I can get it to print the command, but it just doesn't use them!

Any ideas?

Comment: The original code is not valid Python syntax anyway; you can't pass multiple kwargs with the same keyword.

Comment: you cannot have exclude be two different things at once

Comment: Give us exclude list sample

Comment: the resulting aws s3 command would like this.. 
`aws s3 sync ./local/path/ s3://remote/path --exclude="*.txt" --exclude="*.doc"`  so, my `exclude` lists is `exclude=["*.doc","*.txt"]`.   Good point re the multiple kwargs - that was just pseudo code, i've not seen in the `sh` docs how to handle multiple arguments.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yeah, this is AWS.  The whole exclude / include is very counter intuitive, and you can pass multiple --exclude args to the command.

Comment: Ah ok,  could you just use subprocess to run the command or the sh packages is a necessity?

Comment: no, I'm just using it already in the project, and needed to add this extra bit in, so I could do that, was just trying to keep it consistent.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with a mix of `*args` and `*kwargs` in the end.

```
s3=sh.aws.bake('s3')
args = [
  origin,
  destination,
  "--delete"
]

for pattern in exclude:
  args.extend(["--exclude", pattern])

for pattern in include:
  args.extend(["--include", pattern])

kwargs = {'_iter':True}

output = s3.sync( *args, **kwargs )
```